# error: reduction variable is private in outer context (omp reduction)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, simd

I am confused about the data sharing scope of the variable *acc* in the flowing two cases. In the case 1 I get following compilation error: `error: reduction variable ‘acc’ is private in outer context`, whereas the case 2 compiles without any issues.

According to [this article](http://jakascorner.com/blog/2016/06/omp-data-sharing-attributes.html) variables defined outside parallel region are shared.

Why is adding for-loop parallelism privatizing *acc*?
How can I in this case accumulate the result calculated in the the for-loop and distribute a loop's iteration space across a thread team?

**case 1**

```
            float acc = 0.0f;
            
            #pragma omp for simd reduction(+: acc)
            for (int k = 0; k < MATRIX_SIZE; k++) {
                float mul = alpha;
                mul *=  a[i * MATRIX_SIZE + k];
                mul *=  b[j * MATRIX_SIZE + k];
                acc += mul;
            }
```

**case 2**

```
            float acc = 0.0f;
            
            #pragma omp simd reduction(+: acc)
            for (int k = 0; k < MATRIX_SIZE; k++) {
                float mul = alpha;
                mul *=  a[i * MATRIX_SIZE + k];
                mul *=  b[j * MATRIX_SIZE + k];
                acc += mul;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case 1 is violating OpenMP semantics, as there's an implicit parallel region (see [OpenMP Language Terminology](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu2.html#x9-80001.2.2), "sequential part") that contains the definition of `acc`.  Thus, `acc` is indeed private to that implicit parallel region.  This is what the compiler complains about.

Your case 2 is different in that the `simd` construct is not a worksharing construct and thus has a different definition of the semantics of the `reduction` clause.

Case 1 would be correct if you wrote it this way:

```
void example(void) {
    float acc = 0.0f;

    #pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+: acc)
    for (int k = 0; k < MATRIX_SIZE; k++) {
        float mul = alpha;
        mul *=  a[i * MATRIX_SIZE + k];
        mul *=  b[j * MATRIX_SIZE + k];
        acc += mul;
    }
}
```

The `acc` variable is now defined outside of the `parallel` that the `for simd` construct binds to.